# C++ distinguishing structurally identical classes

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have several types that share common behaviour and with same constructors and operators.  Some look like this:

```
class NumberOfFingers
{
public:
    void operator=(int t) { this->value = t; }
    operator int() const { return this->value; }
private:
    int value;
};
```

`NumberOfToes` is identical.

Each class has different behaviour, here is an example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const NumberOfFingers &fingers)
{
    s << fingers << " fingers\n";
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &s, const NumberOfFingers &toes)
{
    s << toes << " toes\n";
}
```

How can I minimise the duplication in the class definitions, whilst keeping class types distinct?  I don't want to have `NumberOfFingers` and `NumberOfToes` derive from a common base class because I lose the constructor and operators.  I would guess a good answer would involve templates.

Comment: What makes you think that inheritance from a common base would make you lose the constructors and operators?

Comment: @Björn What are you saying?  Can a derived class always use base class constructors and operators, if it doesn't have its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in that it would involve templates :)

```
enum {FINGERS, TOES...};
...
template<unsigned Type> //maybe template<enum Type> but I havent compiled this.
class NumberOfType
{
public:
    void operator=(int t) { this->value = t; }
    operator int() const { return this->value; }
private:
    int value;
};
...
typedef NumberOfType<FINGERS> NumberOfFinger
typedef NumberOfType<TOES> NumberOfToes
... so on and so forth.
```

Comment: it might be better to use types instead of enumeration, e.g. 'struct fingers_tag', 'typedef NumberOfType<fingers_tag> NumberOfFinger' and so on. This way you don't need to have a single place specifying all possible type variations.

Comment: @Konstantin Thats very true indeed, depends on whether we want the set of such types to be closed or open. But that certainly is the way to go if we want to keep the set open.